# I need libapr-1.so.0 rpm for RHEL v6.6

Tags: linux, rpm, rhel6

I was installing libapr-util1-1.3.9-4.1.x86_64 on RHEL v6.6 and it requires libapr-1.so.0 as a dependency. I've searched a lot and couldn't find.

The only rpm I found was vulture-common-3.2-185.1.x86_64.rpm which installs a lot of other packages as well that will conflict with already installed servers and software on my machine.

Does anyone know from where I can get this rpm? Or how to select specific part from the rpm to be installed?

Comment: What rpm are you trying to install exactly? Where did it come from?

Comment: libapr-util1-1.3.9-4.1.x86_64.rpm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me `yum whatprovides 'libapr-1.so.0'` shows `apr-1.3.9-5.el6_2.i686` is the package, on my CentOS 6.6.

Answer (score 2):

For CentOS 7.7 I had the same error when trying to configure and compile mesos.

I had to install some additional libraries:

```
sudo yum install -y git apache-maven python-devel java-devel zlib-devel libcurl-devel openssl-devel cyrus-sasl-devel cyrus-sasl-md5 apr-devel subversion-devel apr-util-devel
```

Answer (score 1):

For me yum install  apr , on my CentOS 7.x.

Answer (score 0):

Try to search for apr-1.4.8-7.el7.x86_64.rpm and apr-util-1.5.2-6.e7.x86_64.rpm